# How to pass a linked-list?

Tags: javascript, function, class, linked-list

I was given this as a solution to delete all duplicate numbers in a Linkded list. But I don't understand how to pass in the linked list?

```
var deleteDuplicates = function(head) {
    // sets current node to be head of list
    let current = head
    // runs until we are at the end of the list
    while (current !== null && current.next !== null) { 
        // checks to see if the current value and the next value are the same
        if (current.val === current.next.val){  
            // skips over the duplicate and the next value becomes 2x next
            current.next = current.next.next            
            // current value and the next value are not the same
        } else {  
            // moves to the next node on the list to run through the while again
            current = current.next 
        }
    
    }
    // returns the linked list with no duplicates
    return head  
};
```

Comment: Well the first thing you have to do is build an instance of your `LinkedList` class.

Comment: Also your class does not involve `next` or `val` properties.

Comment: create linked list first using `LinkedList` class and then pass head reference to function.

Comment: Nothing in your class is a linked list? It just holds a normal array.

Comment: You removed the `LinkedList` class from your question, so what now? You certainly need to define the class?? This question is now even more vague. You should at least show *which* linked list you want to pass to the function...

Comment: ....If you don't know how to *create* a linked list, then you should focus your question on that, not on this `deleteDuplicates` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A example to pass a List to function `getListSize()`. Is this what you want?

```js
class ListNode {
    constructor(data) {
        this.data = data
        this.next = null                
    }
}

class LinkedList {
    constructor(head = null) {
        this.head = head
    }
}

let node1 = new ListNode(2)
let node2 = new ListNode(5)
node1.next = node2

let list = new LinkedList(node1)

function getListSize(list){
    let count = 0; 
    let node = list.head;
    while (node) {
        count++;
        node = node.next
    }
    return count;
}

console.log(getListSize(list));
```

Comment: I rephrased the question, I just need to know how to pass a linked list into my solution. 
Thanks.

Comment: @ChaseMiller, This shows how you pass a list to a function.  It is the same to apply to your function.

Answer (score 1):

You created a class but don't instantiate it, to do so call the constructor of the class using the `new` keyword:

```
const instance = new LinkedList();
```

then you need to pass the head property of that instance to the function, currently you are sending an undefined value (head doesn't exist outside the `deleteDuplicates` function's scope).

```
deleteDuplicates(instance.head);
```

i also noticed that your function `deleteDuplicates` won't work for what you want to do, here is a function that should do what you are trying to achieve:

```
function deleteDuplicates(list) {
    if (!Array.isArray(list)) {
        console.error(`Given argument is not an Array: ${list}`);
        return;
    };
    return list.map((element, index, array)=>{
        if (array.indexOf(element)!==index) return undefined;
        return element;
    })
    .filter((element)=>(element!==undefined));
}
```

for more informations about what i said:

how classes work: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/class

understand scope: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope